# Cannot get contact details from some contact

Tags: android, contacts

I've pulled out most of my hair now and really needs some help
before I go completely bold

I'm trying to launch an action picker to select a Contact that has a phone number.
When that contact is selected, I want to extract the name and phone number.

But this only happens for some contacts, not all.
The code is rougly as follows:

Select contact:

```
Intent contactPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, contactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPicker, REQ_PICK_CONTACT);
```

Extract id (notice `getData().getLastPathSegment()`:

```
onContactForImportPicked(intent.getData().getLastPathSegment());
```

and then I try to fetch this contact:

```
String[] fields = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
};

Cursor cursor = content.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
   fields,
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, // SEE BELOW
   null);
```

It this point, many contacts are fetched correctly, but a lot is
also non-existing. `cursor.getCount() == 0`. In the 'SEE BELOW'
section above, I've tried various other fields, linke
`Contact._ID`, `Phone._ID` etc etc.

Any idea why some contacts are not fetched with this method?

Answer (score 0):

When I use your code, I don't even get the contact I selected correctly.  The intent data contains the URI to the data you want, so you can use that directly.

Try --

```
 Cursor cursor = content.query(data.getData(),
                fields,
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot simpler. The same problem applies though. The cursor is empty : getCount() == 0. Strange as I just selected the contact..